# Send scheduled SMSs via Skype

Tags: shell, skype, scheduled-tasks, sms

I would like to send programmed SMSs via Skype. I mean, I write a list with SMSs to different people that says; a) send a 04:30 a SMS to Joe "Wake up please, we meet at 05.30!", and so. The first idea that comes to my mind is somehow to call skype via linux shell using cron (although I do not know the right commands now), are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Perl to do this:

CPAN - Net::DBus::Skype
  http://search.cpan.org/~ecarroll/Net-DBus-Skype-0.02/lib/Net/DBus/Skype.pm

Perl SMS Sender via Skype API – kSMS
  http://intunsigned.co.uk/?p=77